# How to build different apk from root capacitor.config.ts for 2 ionic projects in nx workspace?

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, nomachine-nx

Right now is in root folder there is a single capacitor.config.ts file which includes the configuration for one project only. So if I run './gradlew assembleDevRelease ’ command, it will generate apk for the specified project only. In local I can change the webDir name based on project for which I need to sync capacitor generate apk but on staging we cannot do the same.
Here is the capacitor.config.ts file content.

```
import { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli';

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'com.theraparea.app',
  appName: 'theraparea',
  webDir: 'dist/apps/theraparea.ionic',
  bundledWebRuntime: false
};

export default config;
```

What to modify this file such a way that both the apk can be generated without any manual changes?

I want a solution to give webDir name dynamically so that the build can be generated for both project instead of one